# how to read NON-ASCII Char in the file as ASCII using AWK

Tags: bash, awk, sh

My input file:

```
000000000 vélIstine IOBAN 00000004960
000000000 shankargu kumar 00000000040
TTTTTTTTT                     0000000200000000050000000000000000000000
```

whenever I have non Ascii character in the file like above,

my below code snippet not calculating the sum (d_amt_sum+=substr($0,27,10)) properly sometimes its skiping that row and sometime its giving incorrect value instead of 496 its returning 49 for substr($0,27,10)?

besides I want to know how to add print statement inside AWK, example i need to print the value of "substr($0,27,10)" inside the if block how to do that?

```
 set -A out_result -- `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk 'BEGIN{
    d_amt_sum=d_rec_count=d_trailer_out_amt_sum=d_trailer_rec_count=0;
}
{
    if(substr($0,1,9) != "TTTTTTTTT")
    {
            d_amt_sum+=substr($0,27,10); d_rec_count+=1
    }
            else if(substr($0,1,9) == "TTTTTTTTT")
            {
                    d_trailer_out_amt_sum+=substr($0,39,12);
                    d_trailer_rec_count+=substr($0,31,8);
            }
}
END{print d_amt_sum, d_rec_count,d_trailer_out_amt_sum,d_trailer_rec_count}' ${OUTDIR}/${OUT_FILE}

 Expected output 
500,2,500,2
```

Comment: Non ascii characters like vél

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi am expecting d_amt_sum+=substr($0,27,10) should return 0000000496 from the first line and 0000000004 from second line.. at the end am expecting output d_amt_sum as 500

Comment: Also please tell me how to use print statements inside awk.. I want to print and see the value of substr($0,27,10) inside if block..

Comment: when will this ```if(substr($0,0,1) == "TTTTTTTTT")``` be true?

Comment: wrt [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665324/how-to-read-non-ascii-char-in-the-file-as-ascii-using-awk#comment110819981_62665324) about how to use `print` to see the value of `substr($0,27,10)` inside the if block - that's `print substr($0,27,10)`. Not sure where you were struggling with that since you use `print` and `substr()` elsewhere in your code. As for when will `if(substr($0,0,1) == "TTTTTTTTT")` be true - never since the single character you're selecting using `substr()` can never match the multi-character string of `T`s you're comparing it to.

Comment: I have corrected the logic

Answer (score 2):

you have a logic error on the ordering of the if/else statements, another error on checking 1 char length against 9 char length.  Fixing both gives...

```
awk '{k=substr($0,1,9)
      if(k=="TTTTTTTTT")
         {d_trailer_out_amt_sum+=substr($0,39,12)
          d_trailer_rec_count+=substr($0,31,8)}
      else if(k!="999999999")
         {d_amt_sum+=substr($0,27,10); 
          d_rec_count+=1}}
  END {print d_amt_sum, d_rec_count,d_trailer_out_amt_sum,d_trailer_rec_count}' file

500 2 500 2
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding.. how can we print k value inside else if for every iteration

Comment: just add `print k`

Comment: @jcrshankar you already had code that does `print d_amt_sum` and then you asked how to print the value of `substr($0,27,10)` and [I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665324/how-to-read-non-ascii-char-in-the-file-as-ascii-using-awk#comment110822074_62665324) `print substr($0,27,10)`. Then you asked how to print the value of `k`. What part of the puzzle are we missing that meant you couldn't figure out `print k` was how to print the value of `k` given that you already knew  how to print the values of `d_amt_sum` and `substr($0,27,10)`?